# how to embed paypal donate button on a sharepoint web page

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2010, paypal, web-parts

I'm trying to add a donation button to a sharepoint site, but the sharepoint site already has its own form.

The paypal donate button is auto generate code from paypal that looks like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">...</form>
```

When I add this code to the web part in sharepoint the form tags are removed.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this document](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/insert-a-paypal-button-in-a-public-facing-webpage-HA101848175.aspx) help?  There is quite a bit about Sharepoint and PayPal buttons when I do some general Google searching.  I haven't used Sharepoint myself, though, so unfortunately I can't help beyond that.

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with SharePoint and I can't find any Gadgets menu.